# image to text in signup process

Tags: web-applications

I am in the training of web developement.I have seen in most of the websites while registering new user it shows one image and tells the user to type the characters in the image.I dont know What is the use of that process? Is there any reason behind that?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to validate that the entity signing into the web site is actually a person and not a program.  The *thing* is called a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captcha), which stands for "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart."

Answer (score 0):

It avoids automatic process.Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

CAPTCHA's (as spelled out above) serve as a method for preventing web crawlers and spam bots from submitting forms automatically as they traverse the web. CAPTCHA's are meant to ensure that it is in fact a human behind the keyboard inputting the form because an automated bot would generally be unable to decipher the text in the image.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing a CAPTCHA, be sure not do like this site: http://bebotechnologies.com/apply1.php

If you look the source code you can see it in plain text!